Cannot change after:content value if it is dynamically passed like `after:content-[${type1}]`
I'm trying to dynamically change the values of a custom made toggle button in react, but it's not changing. It seems like the problem is in after:content-[]. It is accepting static values, but passing dynamic values won't work. Below is my component code...

function ToggleOnSteroid({changeType, type1, type2}) {
    return (
        <div className="w-full">
            <label className="relative w-full inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
                <input className="sr-only peer " value="" type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>{
                    if(e.target.checked){
                        changeType(type1.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ','-'));
                    }else{
                        changeType(type2.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ','-'));
                    }
                }}/>
                    <div 

                    className={`peer rounded-md outline-none duration-100 after:duration-500 w-full h-[52px] bg-white border border-gray-300 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-2 peer-focus:ring-[#B5A352]  
                        
                        after:content-["Ac"] 
                                after:absolute after:outline-none after:rounded-md after:h-[44px] after:w-[120px] after:bg-[#B5A352] after:top-1 after:left-1 after:flex after:justify-center after:items-center  after:text-white     after:font-bold peer-checked:after:translate-x-24 
                        peer-checked:after:content-["${type2}"] 
                        
                                peer-checked:after:border-white`}
                    >

                    </div>
            </label>

        </div>
    )
}

The below part works,
after:content-["Ac"]
but this won't work
after:content-["${type2}"]
Is there a solution like some new formatting way to fix this?

This is fundamentally how Tailwind works, you cannot dynamically form strings. They all need to be known ahead of time at build. You need to always form complete class names, and toggle between them.
// DON'T
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

// DO
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>

How you handle this depends a bit on what type2 is; if it's a union, you can easily do something like the above.
See Tailwind's docs.

thankyou very much,
i did ma mapping for all possible parameters, and added values in className, now it works fine,
 const propsMap = {         "ac": "after:content-['Ac']",         "non-ac": "peer-checked:after:content-['Non-Ac']",         "extra-bed": "after:content-['Extra-Bed']",         "no-extra-bed": "peer-checked:after:content-['No-Extra-Bed']",         "pick-up-drop": "after:content-['PickUp-Drop']",         "no-pick-up-drop": "peer-checked:after:content-['No-PickUp-Drop']",     } and className={${propsMap[type1]}} 
